# How the while loop works with promise and callback function in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, loops, promise, callback

This is my first time to write while loop with Promise and callback. I don't know why it leads to infinite loop. How to fix it?

```
async function getResult(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let params ="some input and setting";
        let next = "hasNext";
        let array = [];
        let error = null;
        while(next !== null){
            checkNext(params, function(err,data) { //checkNext is a function to return the current list and check wether there has the next list
                if(err){
                    next = null;
                    error = err;
                }else{
                    next = data.hasNext; // if there is not next list, data.hasNext = null
                    array = array.concat(data.array); // data.array return the current list
                }
            });
        }
        if(error !== null){
            reject(error);
        }else{
            resolve(array); // I want to return all lists
        }
       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It leads to an infinite loop because `checkNext()` is asynchronous and non-blocking so your `while()` just runs forever before even one call to `checkNext()` gets a chance to finish and call its callback.

You never use a `while()` loop waiting for some asynchronous things to finish in Javsacript (except with `await` as shown below) because with the event driven architecture of nodejs, the while loop never returns control back to the event loop so no asynchronous operation can never get its completion event processed and thus the thing you are waiting for never gets a chance to happen.  Things are different (as shown below) if you use `await` to await a promise that is connected to your asynchronous event.  Then, you can use a `while()` loop successfully.

With asynchronous operations where you're going to use promises, you pretty much always want to promisify your asynchronous operations so all your control flow is with promises, not plain callbacks as the two don't mix very well.  This is what I would suggest:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const checkNextP = promisify(checkNext);

async function getResult() {
    let params = "some input and setting";
    let next = "hasNext";
    let array = [];
    while (next !== null) {
        let data = await checkNextP(params);
        next = data.hasNext;               // if there is not next list, data.hasNext = null
        array = array.concat(data.array);  // data.array return the current list
    }
    return array;
}
```

Here, the `while` loop works because we're using `await` with a promise returned from `checkNextP()` and that `await` suspends the execution of the function until that promise resolves/rejects.

**A little more explanation about how async functions work**

At the point we hit the first `await` this `async` function will automatically return a promise.  The caller will get that promise at that point.  Then, when the promise with that first `await` resolves, the function will resume, you will get the first `data` value and the rest of your loop executes.  This process will repeat until `next` is `null`.  At that point, your `while()` loop will be done and the `return array` statement will execute.  Because this is an `async` function, what that return statement really does is it resolves the promise that the `async` function previously returned and sets the `array` to be the resolved value of that promise.

If, the promise from `checkNextP()` rejects, then the `await checkNextP()` will throw the rejection and since we don't have a `try/catch` around it, the `async` function will automatically catch that throw and it will reject the promise that the `async` function has previously returned, causing the caller to get a promise rejection with whatever error `checkNextP()` rejected with.  So, the error handling here works too.

The caller of `getResult()`, just needs to do something like this:

```
getResult().then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Or, the caller could also be in an `async` function itself and use `await` and `try/catch` to catch errors.

Comment: I wanted to write more or less the same but you did it faster. And better. I'd just want to leave a useful link for reference: [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784)

Comment: Thanks, my friend.  A lot of things learn from your post.

Comment: @LiLian - Glad that explained things for you.  If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.